# how can i find the highest even and odd number in 2D matrix using python3

Tags: python-3.x

how can i do this using simple code in python3

```
matrix = [[98, 19, 1, 46, 51, 33, 3, 33, 80, 40], [26, 88, 79, 10, 63, 76, 18, 49, 47, 44], [18, 53, 8, 96, 40, 53, 73, 8, 31, 43], [8, 40, 31, 98, 19, 39, 15, 9, 58, 32], [76, 45, 1, 5, 15, 14, 20, 88, 51, 48]
```

Comment: What have you tried, ever heard of modulus?

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your list via `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, then get the largest even and odd using `%==0` for evens and `%!=0` for odds:

```
import itertools

flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matrix))

even_max = max(i for i in flat if i%2==0)
odd_max = max(i for i in flat if i%2!=0)

>>> even_max
98
>>> odd_max
79
```

If you prefer to avoid `itertools`, you can flatten your 2d matrix by list comprehension:

```
flat = [v for i in matrix for v in i]

even_max = max(i for i in flat if i%2==0)
odd_max = max(i for i in flat if i%2!=0)
```

More options, with `numpy` (might be overkill for your matrix, but could be beneficial if your matrix were huge):

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array(matrix)
even_max = max(m[m%2==0])
odd_max = max(m[m%2!=0])
```